# Fastest way to add columns when there in inter-row dependency?

Tags: python, pandas

I am working on a problem that has a dataframe with family information. Each family is made of one or more parents and children. Each person has a unique UserID and each family has a unique FamilyID. One person can belong to only one family. The Type column indicates whether the person is parent or child and Age indicates age of the user.

I would like to add a column called ParentAge for children that indicates the age of the oldest parent.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

#example data
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 22, 'Child', 8], 
                   [1, 62, 'Parent', 36],
                   [2, 102, 'Child', 6],
                   [2, 103, 'Child', 10],
                   [2, 107, 'Parent', 40],
                   [2, 108, 'Parent', 42]], 
                  columns=['FamilyId', 'UserId', 'Type', 'Age'])

expected_result = pd.DataFrame([[1, 22, 'Child', 8, 36], 
                   [2, 102, 'Child', 6, 42],
                   [2, 103, 'Child', 10, 42]], 
                  columns=['FamilyId', 'UserId', 'Type', 'Age', 'ParentAge'])
```

Here is what I have tried so far (I've tried few other ways, but the perf is roughly similar)

```py
parents = df.query('Type=="Parent"')
children = df.query('Type=="Child"')

oldest_parents = parents.groupby('FamilyId') \
    .apply(pd.DataFrame.nlargest, n=1, columns='Age') \
    .reset_index(drop=True) \
    .rename(columns={'Age': 'ParentAge'})

pd.merge(children, oldest_parents[['FamilyId', 'ParentAge']], on='FamilyId')
```

The method above works, but for a dataframe to close to a million rows, its taking 20+ hours to complete. All other techniques were in the same ballpark. It took me couple seconds to do this in R using dplyr library. I was wondering if there is a faster way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option 1**: Try `groupby().max()` instead of `apply`:

```
df[df['Type'].eq('Child')].merge(df[df['Type'].eq('Parent')].groupby('FamilyId').Age.max(),
                                 on='FamilyId',
                                 suffixes=('','Parent'))
```

**Option 2**: Fastest, *assuming oldest parent is also the oldest in family*:

```
df['Parent_Age'] = df.groupby('FamilyId').Age.transform('max')
df[df['Type'].eq('Child')]
```

**Option 3**: Faster, without assuming parents are oldest (e.g., grant parents):

```
df['Parent_Age'] = (df['Age'].mul(df['Type'].eq('Parent'))
                             .groupby(df['FamilyId']).transform('max')
                   )
df[df['Type'].eq('Child')]
```

**Output**:

```
   FamilyId  UserId   Type  Age  AgeParent
0         1      22  Child    8         36
1         2     102  Child    6         42
2         2     103  Child   10         42
```

Comment: i like this approach